# "Independent" execution of appscript on copied files

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm G-Suite user. I have a combo of google docs consisting of Form with attached Sheet and bounded AppScript. Based on Form replies saved to sheet the script connects to the Slides modifies it, fetches result as PDF and send it via MailApp. Lets call it "the Combo". I use the combo for every new event, this however requires clearing past data and the old data is lost. That's why I need to modify it in a certain way.

#### Reuired process

For every new event I'd like create following process:
*please note, I'm not asking for advice on how to complete steps 1-3 - that's pretty straightforward*
 1. Admin opens the "Master" Spreadsheet having additional menu item created (say: "create new event") - the popup appears
 2. In the pop-up Admin enters event details, presses OK.
 3. Script in the spreadsheet creates a copy of the combo folder sends the link to the Form to predefined users via email. 
 4. Once there's a reply in the copied form combo suppose to get **activated** to do what it need to do (as described above).

As you see there has to be no human intervention other than firing up creation of the copied combo by Admin and external users filling in shared Form that fires up the process described above. The users of the form are anonymous - not Gsuite/Google users.

#### Problems

Most triggers on copied files will not get activated even if assigned via GAS due to OAuth or other internal limitations. I believe that only way to get this done is creating domain-wide add-on (maybe for Sheets) but it seems it will still require authorisation before the copied combo may access the files/data. 
As you see the problem is not creating files and folders but ACTIVATING the process once the files are copied. It looks what could do the job is setting up the trigger `onFormSubmit()` for copied Form which will also **automatically** allow `Form App`, `DriveApp`, `SpreadsheetApp`, `SlidesApp`, `MailApp` scopes, which won't happen unless authorised in the way I do not know. 
Could anyone enlighten me on this topic please

Many thanks

Rafal

Answer (score 1):

### Considerations

When you create the copies you will need to run the trigger installation functions. Only installable triggers can use those permissions you need to run your routine.

If you create copies of the files a user without a g-suite/gmail account will never be able to install the triggers you want to use.
Please consider that triggers on Forms only run in the editor.

### Approach

The idea is to create another Admin step let's say 3a:

Once you create the new combo folder you should keep track of the ids of each new google docs created. Now is the moment to install all the triggers for the new documents using their IDs. Now these triggers will run with your admin privileges and permissions.

In your case the only trigger you should create is a `onFormSubmit` which catches the form submission, creates the Slides and and sends the Email.

### References:

[Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)